# How to filter rows for a pivot chart to ensure one to one relationship in results

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts, pivot-chart

I am trying to put together a PivotChart as such:

[image: Line Graph displaying data]

Each recipe is made up of ingredients. Each ingredient maps to (potentially) many products. Croissant Dough for instance calls for 40g of butter. There are two choices for the ingredient butter, a fancy European style or a generic butter (both are products that satisfy this ingredient.) I want to be able to choose between these different products so that I can see the change in overall cost depending on which products I use. I also expect to eventually incorporate multiple vendors for the same products (vendor A may offer a better price than vendor B for the fancy butter) but for now I am only using a single vendor for my cost data.

Here is what the raw data looks like:

[image: The raw data as I currently have it structured]

I have highlighted the "Butter" rows.

Since I am doing a PivotChart, by default both "Butter" products are being totaled as part of the overall recipe cost. This means both the fancy butter and the generic butter are both factoring into the cost. I can add a filter to remove whichever products need to be ignored, but I am worried that other users won't understand this is necessary. For longer recipes this becomes more complicated and the chances of making a mistake are greater.

What I really want is to force the user to choose one product for each ingredient (and for each vendor.) Maybe I need to build some kind of a selection menu with VBA? I tried using slicers but I couldn't get that to work either. I am open to any suggestions, but the order should be something like:

1. Choose the recipe
2. For each ingredient with multiple products that satisfy, choose only one of the products
3. For each product with multiple vendors that sell this product, choose only one of these vendors
4. View resulting ingredient cost over time chart